# Highest point along Up Vector

Tags: vector, quaternions, coordinate-systems

We have normal 3 axis cordinate system. Then we have a vector, say "Up Vector" which can be inclined in any direction, and we have couple of points say P1, P2, P3, P4.

[Check this pic for info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a44Ol.jpg)

Now, normal if we wanted to check which of these point is highest amongst all we simply check it's Y cordinate(assuming it's the vertical axis).

But I want to :

Find the highest point along the "Up Vector".
And later, Translate other remaining points by suitable amount along the "Up Vector" to bring all points to the same level as the Highest one.

**Remember we want highest point along the Up vector**

How to do this ?

Comment: Come on guys no one knows ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code does that :

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

import numpy as np
from pyquaternion import Quaternion

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

# draw vector

world_up = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
local_up = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

ax.quiver(*world_up, color='r')
ax.quiver(*local_up, color='b')


def normalize(vec):
    normalized_v = vec / np.linalg.norm(vec)
    return normalized_v


vector1 = normalize(np.array(world_up[3:]))
vector2 = normalize(np.array(local_up[3:]))

points = [np.array([0.1, 0.4, 0.5]) + vector2*0.2,
          np.array([0.2, 0.5, 0.3]),
          np.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.3]),
          np.array([0.4, 0.1, 0.5]) - vector2*0.2]

for index, point in enumerate(points):
    ax.scatter(*point)

dot_product = vector1.dot(vector2)
theta_rad = np.arccos(dot_product)
theta_deg = np.rad2deg(theta_rad)

vector3 = normalize(np.cross(vector1, vector2))

rotator = Quaternion(axis=vector3, angle=-theta_rad)

highest = 0
highest_index = 0
for index, point in enumerate(points):
    new_point = rotator.rotate(point)
    if new_point[2] > highest:
        highest = new_point[2]
        highest_index = index
    ax.scatter(*new_point, c='gray')

ax.text(*rotator.rotate(points[highest_index]), "Highest", 'z', c='red')
ax.text(*points[highest_index], "Highest", 'z', c='red')

ax.set_xlim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_zlim([-1.5, 1.5])
ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')
ax.set_title("Vectors")

plt.show()
```

[Check results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igXEQ.jpg)

Can anyone plz suggest improvement or alternate way.